# How to access camera or webcam in kaggle?

Tags: python, data-science, webcam, face-detection, kaggle

I tried using a webcam in Kaggle to take capture for the face detection project. but it's not working.

> code working well in Jupyter Notebook in the system

here is the code that I'm using :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

for imgnum in range(number_images):
    print('Collectiong image {}'.format(imgnum))
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH,f'{str(uuid.uuid1())}.jpg')
    cv2.imwrite(imgname,frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this is the error that Kaggle shows :
Collectiong image 0

> [ WARN:0] global
> /tmp/pip-req-build-jpmv6t9_/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp
> (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- error                                     Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_27/1415701618.py in 
> 4     ret,frame = cap.read()
> 5     imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH,f'{str(uuid.uuid1())}.jpg')
> ----> 6     cv2.imwrite(imgname,frame)
> 7     cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
> 8     time.sleep(1)
>
> error: OpenCV(4.5.4)
> /tmp/pip-req-build-jpmv6t9_/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:799:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

note: I tried to use 1,2 values in cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) . but is not working.

if any body has any way please write. thankyou

Comment: This does not look like it is possible, maybe try google colab: https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/90890